# How do I access an array that is called from inside a function outside of an object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I'm working with ES 6 and I have a an array assigned to an object like so.

`let myArray = [];`

further down in my object I have a a function assigned to a handler like so.

`myFunction: doSomething`

Now outside of the object I define the function.

`const doSomething = function(arg){}`

So my problem is that when I try to assign something to the array inside of this outer function JavaScript has no idea what that thing is.

I can't figure out how to access this global array inside of the object. So when I to assign a value to this array I get an error.

```
class myObject {
   var myArray = [],
   myFunction: doSomething,
}

const doSomething = function(arg) {
    let selected = $.map(this.select(), (item) => {
        this.myArray[this.dataItem(item).Id] = true;
    });
}
```

Comment: I tried let at first then switched it to var

Comment: Pretty sure neither `let` nor `var` are valid syntax there... Nor is `myFunction: doSomething`. Are you getting any errors? It appears as though you're trying to use object literal syntax with the `class` keyword.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan wow, totally missed that one. i never use js classes. i'm gonna show myself out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have shown for `class myObject` is not valid syntax.

You can't declare a variable such as `var myArray = []` in a class declaration like that. Similarly, `myFunction: doSomething,` is not correct either.  See the proper ES6 `class` syntax [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes).

If you want to initialize a property on the object, then you can do that inside the constructor with `this.myArray = []` and then you can access `this.myArray` inside any method.  Here's is some valid syntax:

```
class myObject {
   constructor() {
       this.myArray = [];
   }

   myFunction(arg) {
       let selected = $.map(this.select(), (item) => {
           this.myArray[this.dataItem(item).Id] = true;
       });
   }
}
```

Then, you would use it as:

```
var x = new myObject();
x.myFunction();
```

I also notice that the method `myFunction` assumes there are other methods `dataItem()` and `select()` so you would have to define those methods too for this code to work.